# Font resources not working properly with font when using Html texts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

I was using [calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) before the [Font resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource), one we see this we moved to Font resources and all works well,only one problem i am getting if my text view content is html and bold attribute(),its not highlighting, but if i remove the Font resources via xml and use the programmatic way it is working with same font.

i can give an example
i am using **Font resources** like below

**font_regular.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<font
    app:font="@font/myfont"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="700"  />
</font-family>
```

**My textview**

```
  <TextView
        app:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
```

When i apply this to a html data contain bold,all data is coming from server as html data like example data as below

***Data***

```
<p>Hi i am <b>bold</b></p>
```

Expected result

Hi i am **bold**

But out put will be

Hi i am bold

The font is applying successfully but the portion of bold is not getting bold

But when i use programmatically via Typeface its working

**Programmatically**

```
 Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/myfont.otf");
```

I google and gone through all the doc that i have seen via google none of them pointing me how to achieve this via Font resources.

Please help me to know whether i can achieve this via Font resources

Comment: Can you please update the code you are using to set text? Also clarify are you testing it on device running Marshmallow or lower versions?

Comment: @Pramod Moolekandathil The code i are using to set text is the html text i had given in the question itself i marked it as Data for you clarity this is the text                                      <p>Hi i am <b>bold</b></p> , i run in all device android pie,marshmallow,oreio,even in gingerbread, font is applying but the area i need to get bold is not setting

Comment: I guess the trick is to use a `font-family`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: i also had the same problem, final stick with programmatic way and used calligraphy

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to achieve similar functionality in some apps and it worked really. I hope this could help

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    mDescTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else {
    Spanned myHtmlText = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getContext(), myHtmlText, 0);
    mDescTextView.setText(myHtmlText);
}
```

Alright. If this is not working for you and as you mentioned in question font working when programmatically adding typeface, i have an alternative in that case. This may not be the exact answer you are looking for. But i think it will help in long run. No need to set typeface programmatically, neither have to add font face in xml. Using your own textview class will automatically load the font everywhere, also you can set thickness using the attributes (in values/attrs.xml) declared.

```
<com.youpackage.yourapp.view.customview.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:hint="@string/label_full_name"
    app:customFontThickness="bold"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

For the custom textview class and attribute declaration see this.
https://github.com/pramodpmk/CustomTextView

Comment: i am setting all properly same as above

Comment: Ok. I have an alternative that could help you. Instead of using TextView, use a custom one by extending TextView class. Add stylable attributes in attrs.xml file. Then use it inside you layout xml. I have updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score -1):

Add this

String str = Hi i am + "**" + bold + "** ";
tv_view.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));

Comment: But the content is html for example as i give in the question it is <p>Hi i am <b>bold</b></p> and it not a static data its coming from server as html